# Taking input array, doing one mathematical function and then looping back for another 3 functions

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Below is the task I am stuck on, I am using `python` to achieve it:

> First, take the input array values from the first loop sequence and
>   set them up so that a mathematical function (like add) is done with
>   the values, then output to screen. Loop back to do a different
>   function with the values. In total, use all four functions. Take a
>   screenshot and note on the results.

**Here is my current code:**

```
a = input('Enter a value: ')
b = input('Enter a value: ')
c = input('Enter a value: ')
d = input('Enter a value: ')
e = input('Enter a value: ')
f = input('Enter a value: ')
g = input('Enter a value: ')
h = input('Enter a value: ')
i = input('Enter a value: ')
j = input('Enter a value: ')
list1 = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]


again = input("Do you want to do some math?")
if again == "y":

        add = (list1 + list1)
        print (add)

        again = input ("Want to play again? y/n")

elif again == "n":
        sub = (list1 - list1)
        print (sub)


else:
        mult = (list1 * list1)
        print (mult)
break
```

I need the user to input 10 numbers which is saved into an array variable. After that I need to create a loop that will do one mathematical function (ie. Add) and then loop back around to do another 3 functions (ie. Sub, Mult, and Div).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your asking:

```
#This is where I will store all the values of the inputs
values=[]
#Here i will use a for loop to loop through and ask the user several times to grab some user intger data
for loop in range(10):
    values.append(int(input('Enter a value: '))) #I then ask the user 11 times for an interger value which I then append to list called values
#The rest you should be able to figure it out...

again = input("Do you want to do some addition?(y/n)")
if again == "y":
        add=0
        for value in values:
            add+=value
        print (add)

        again = input ("Subtract=y multiply=n)")

if again == "y":
        sub=0
        for value in values:
            sub-=value
        print (sub)


else:
    mult=1
    for value in values:
        mult*=value
    print (mult)
```

Any questions please ask!

Comment: That helps a ton! Thank you so much. I understand the logic of what I'm trying to do, just couldn't think of what the code would look like.

Answer (score -1):

This I believe is what you want, although maybe the mathematical functions may be different, either way it's better if you do stuff in a modular way so it's easier to read

```
def get_numeric_input():
    try:
        return int(raw_input('Insert a number: '))
    except ValueError:
        print 'A number must be entered'
        return get_numeric_input()


def get_answer(again=None):
    if not again:
        answer = raw_input('Do you want to do some math? ')
    else:
        answer = raw_input('Do you want to play again? ')
    if answer in ['y', 'Y']:
        return True
    elif answer in ['n', 'N']:
        return False
    print 'Either Y or N are the accepted answers'
    return get_answer(again)


def perform_math(iteration, inputs):
    functions = ['Add', 'Sub', 'Mult']
    print functions[iteration]
    if iteration == 0:
        return sum(inputs)
    elif iteration == 1:
        return sum([inputs[0]] + [-x for x in inputs[1:]])
    elif iteration == 2:
        return reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, inputs)
    raise ValueError



inputs = []
for _ in xrange(10):
    inputs.append(get_numeric_input())

again = False
for i in xrange(3):
    if get_answer(again):
        again = True
        print perform_math(i, inputs)
    else:
        break
```